# FPDF include font no longer works with PHP8

Tags: php, fpdf

I am updating PHP 7.4 scripts to PHP 8.2 and an FPDF script no longer works, with this error message:

```
Warning: include(unisansregular.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ (...) /fpdf.php on line 1145
```

I add the fonts like this:

```
$pdf=new PDF_MC_Table();
$pdf->AddFont('Uni-Sans-Regular','','unisansregular.php');
```

What makes it work with PHP7 and not PHP8?

Comment: I suspect some old-style constructor is no longer being invoked.

Comment: Where is unisansregular.php? And which version of FPDF are you using?

Comment: > Where is unisansregular.php? 
In /font/

>And which version of FPDF are you using?
Version: 1.7

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by updating FPDF from V1.7 to V1.86.

(Thanks @Olivier for asking the right question in comments.)

Comment: v1.7 is from 2011 and it features old-style constructors that were deprecated in PHP/7 and [removed in PHP/8](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php#migration80.incompatible.core.other).